# Cannot select an item from combobox using Selenium IDE in GWT applications?

Tags: selenium-ide

I’m working with Selenium IDE in GWT applications. I meet the problem when choosing value from combobox.

My Selenium IDE Source like this:

```
<!—Select value from combobox -->
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//*[@id=&quot;x-auto-174-input&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAt</td>
    <td>//html/body/div[5]/div/div[12]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

This source can select an item of this combobox but Selenium IDE show this error “[error] Element //html/body/div[5]/div/div[12] not found” after selecting this item. Note that I can find this element in Selenium IDE.

Please give me some suggestion to fix this. Is there any way to select value from combobox?

Thanks to much!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <tr>
        <td>click</td>
        <td>//*[@id=&quot;x-auto-174-input&quot;]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mouseDown</td>
        <td>//html/body/div[5]/div/div[12]</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Or try this

```
    <tr>
    <td>click</td>
     <td>//*[@id=&quot;x-auto-174-input&quot;]</td>
     <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Select</td>
        <td>//html/body/div[5]/div/div[12]</td>
        <td> name of Control</td>
    </tr>
```

Let me know your problem is solved or not

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved this problem. :) I use "mouseDown" command.

My source:

```
<!—Select value from combobox -->
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>//*[@id=&quot;x-auto-174-input&quot;]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>mouseDown</td>
    <td>//html/body/div[5]/div/div[12]</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```